# Можно ли запустить программу на чужом рабочем столе от своего имени?

Tags: windows

При установке программы пользователь даёт мне права администратора.

Далее я могу создать задачу для запуска приложения с расширенными правами от имени пользователя System. как я понимаю, это приложение запускается на рабочем столе System (если этот стол вообще существует, ведь увидеть мы его не можем?).

Могу ли я из этой программы запускать на рабочем столе обычного (не администратора) любого пользователя программы от имени System? Чтобы в итоге у пользователя была запущенная программа с расширенными правами.

---

Мне нужно, чтобы в конечном итоге на рабочем столе пользователя запускалась программа с правами администратора. Варианты с сохранением паролей не проходят, так как пароли могут меняться. Каждый раз просить доступ - тоже не вариант. Возможно мне нужно создавать свой window service, но его отличие от приложения запущенного через планировщик от имени system в рамках своей задачки я не вижу, так как в итоге мне все равно надо на рабочем столе обычного пользователя запустить программу с расширенными правами. Или это вообще бред и мне надо перекроить свое приложение и в сервис вывести вес функционал, а под пользователем запускать ещё одно приложение - пользовательский интерфейс управления этим сервисом?

Comment: Лучше бы узнать какой функцонал у проги.

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191416 чтобы лучше понять какой подход предложить.

Comment: Программа читает видео с веб-камера и я не хочу, чтобы доступ к камере зависел от настроек пользователя. Программа использует ресурсы (файлы) недоступные обычному пользователю. Программа должна обновляться через Интернет.

Comment: Т.е. ты хочешь полагаться на виндовые настройки пользователя и согласно им - раздавать права доступа на функционал внутри своей проги?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Как пример: есть файл, который может открыть администратор и не может обычны пользователь, моя программа должна быть способна его открывать, а пользователь нет. Это как один из вариантов.

Comment: Конкретно этот пример - тупо NTFS-ный ACL. Я так студентам доступ в папку со служебными скриптами ограничиваю даже на просмотр. Работает отлично. Никаких паролей не надо. Хардкоришь юзера\группу - и всё едет (могу пример в виде ansible сбросить как я это делал). Давай ещё примеры.

Comment: У пользователя не должно быть прав закрыть приложение, т.е. даже через диспетчер задач он не должен иметь возможности её убить.

Comment: 1. https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/disabling-windows-close-button/?ID=144aa2d3-c5f1-418b-8342-de833f50bd84 - если я всё правильно понял. 2. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/181181/Disabling-Close-window-option-in-windows-7

Comment: Да программа-то моя,  могу заблокировать любые события закрытия, но процесс в котором она крутится принадлежит пользователю, а значит он его может убить. Я кажется нашел, что искал, paexec отличная утилита, не раз выручала, но про эту её функцию я не знал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910831/runas-in-another-windows-terminal-session

PsExec.exe данная утилита позволяет запускать программы на чужом рабочем столе, но от своего имени. Например:

```
    PsExec.exe -i 2 cmd.exe
```

Список сессий можно получить через консольную команду query session, но есть и другие варианты, я использовал Windows API причем в Java через JNA.

Comment: Если прога будет запущена от другого юзера - закрыть её всё равно можно будет.

Comment: Как? Обычный пользователь вроде не имеет прав на закрытие процессов других пользователей.